# Can't find SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, installation

I installed SharePoint Foundation 2010 on my development machine about two months ago and now I changed computers and I cannot find the installation file any more. I didn't think it would be this big of a problem, so I didn't save the original installation file...

All links on the Microsoft site and all blogs I have found point to the same place:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5970 and that one is broken.

Does anyone know if it has moved or if a safe version can be found anywhere else? I am usually quite good at using Google, but this time I admit defeat...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course I manage to find it on the first try after asking...

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24983

Comment: wow.. they have wrong link on the SharePoint Foundation 2010 description page! (weird)

Comment: It's very strange, I have gotten the impression earlier that they are good at keeping their site updated and redirecting old links to new pages...